# Vim replace content from file with output from external command

Tags: go, vim

I am programming go and I want to run `gofmt` with a shortcut and replace the content of the current source file with the output of `gofmt`.

I have the following mapping defined in my vimrc:
`map <C-r> :r ! gofmt %<CR>` but this does simply append the output to the current file. Is there a way to override it?

Comment: As an aside, why don't you use `vim-go`. It does this already

Comment: And run `goimports` instead of `gofmt`.

Comment: If you don't want to use vim-go and automate formatting on save, add the following line to the `.vimrc` file. `:autocmd BufWritePost *.go silent ! go fmt % 2>&1 >/dev/null`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the wrong command: `:read` *appends* lines to the buffer (with `! {cmd}`: from an external command). Instead, you want to *filter* the current buffer contents through an external command. This is done via `:help :range!`. The `gofmt` command reads from stdin when no file is passed (some other commands take a special `-` argument for that. Ergo:

```
:nnoremap <C-r> :%! gofmt<CR>
```

#### Notes

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- I've limited the mapping to *normal mode*; I don't think is necessary to directly launch this from visual mode or operator-pending mode.
- As mentioned in the comments, there's probably a plugin that already provides this out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

The `gofmt flag -w` will overwrite the contents of the file it's fixing